# Java Efficient way for printing list objects between diferrent files

Tags: java, file

I have a List contains Objects

```
Object{
int group
String name

...
....}
```

I create number of files as the group id's.
In order to print the list elements to the different files, I go over the list and each object is written to its group file.
For example :

```
Object {
group - 3
name - RUth
}
```

will be written to file named 3.

```
Object {
group - 2
name - Dan
```

}

will be written to file named 2.

I have about `+700,000` lists in the element.
Is there any efficient way to write it to the different files?

Comment: sorted list would be efficient

Comment: Well, you could sort so files are written sequentially. I mean: 1. Open file "1", write all "1" ... 2. Open file "2" , write all "2"s ... In order to avoid open/close for each object and scattering the files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a `java.util.Map<Integer, List<Object>>` where the key would be the id of a group and value a list of objects from that group. Iterate through the list of objects populating the map. Iterate through the map entries submitting each list of objects to an executor from a pool of executors which will be writing the list to a single file.

Comment: Would it be helpful if I sort the list before?

Comment: Only a proper performance testing can give the right answer. Build a solution with sorted and unsorted list and give it a try. I would say that compared to I/O operations of writing to files, sorting records in memory wouldn't make a big difference.

Comment: You are right. It is not such a big different. Thanks